# Bug: Config Minio for nginx and public url

Tags: minio

How to config .env / config/config.yaml for minio.
By the way, the url is https schema .
the server is depend on nginx
I am using Source Code Deployment .
I want to config minio and work efficient in url binding.

Can be configured to meet conditions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nginx Configuration:

```
upstream minio_s3_2 {
    least_conn;
    server 127.0.0.1:10005;
}

location ^~/im-minio-api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_pass http://minio_s3_2/; # This uses the upstream directive definition to load balance
}
```

2.open-im-server/config/config.yaml Configuration:

```
object:
enable: "minio"
apiURL: "https://lin.blooming.cool/api" //10002
minio:
bucket: "openim"
endpoint: "http://172.28.0.1:10005"
accessKeyID: "root"
secretAccessKey: "openIM123"
sessionToken: ''
signEndpoint: "https://lin.blooming.cool/im-minio-api" //10005
```